# Apache Spark error: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1.f$1

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to trying out Spark, and I made a very simple test class:

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark").setMaster("spark://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:7077"));
JavaRDD<String> inputRDD = jsc.textFile("test.txt");

JavaRDD<String> ones = inputRDD.filter(s -> s.contains("1"));
for (String s : ones.collect()) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

The spark cluster is running in an VM with 1 active worker, and I am running the code from a locally. What I find is that if I call the for loop on inputRDD, it prints out the content of test.txt successfully (a bunch of 1s and 2s in each line). If I do not call the for loop at all, the code also does not complain about inputRDD.filter(s -> s.contains("1")); and exits okay. But as soon as I do anything with the ones javaRDD, it fails with:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1.f$1 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2233)
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1405)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2283)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2277)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2277)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2277)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:426)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
[2018-05-10 17:53:37,511] ERROR [org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager] - Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 192.168.22.240, executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1.f$1 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2233)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1405)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2283)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2277)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2277)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2277)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:426)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2067)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
        at ixl.sparkClusterTest.SparkTest.execute(SparkTest.java:44)
        at ixl.conf.commandLine.RunCommandLineProgram.main(RunCommandLineProgram.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1.f$1 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2233)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1405)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2283)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2277)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2277)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2277)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:426)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any suggestions on why this might be happening will be helpful. Both the VM and local is running on Java 8.

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide the main class code as well. I tried your code and it works perfect

Comment: Hi Ramesh, This is the main class code, in a way. We use a framework for running command line scripts at work and it is the execute() method, and the code I posted is the entirety of what's inside that.

Comment: as i told you that i tried the code and it works without such errors